# Rails, active storage, attach_one photo, doesn't work when fetching photo from folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, photo, seed

So I am trying to attach a picture to an instance of my database, but I can't find the correct path syntax to fetch it from my `images` folder. What am I doing wrong?

It works fine when I host an image on my server with this syntax:

`bar1.photo.attach(io: URI.open("https://www.ogsoundfx.com/ogcoding/photo_test/image1.jpg"), filename: 'bar1')`

But this doesn't work:

`bar1.photo.attach(io: File.open('../../app/assets/images/bar1.jpg'), filename: 'bar1')`

Here is a capture of the `seed.rg` file from where I am running this code:
[image]

Is my path wrong? To be honest I tried every possible way I could think of, but never made it work.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean replacing ```attach``` with ```service_url``` ? Like this:
```bar1.photo.service_url(io: File.open('../../app/assets/images/bar1.jpg'), filename: 'bar1')```
Unfortunately that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want is `Rails.root`. As you can see in [this api documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/root/class) this method returns a **Pathname** object which handles paths starting with a / as absolute (starting from the root of the filesystem).

```
bar1.photo.attach(io: File.open(File.join(Rails.root,'app/assets/images/bar1.jpg')), filename: 'bar1')
```

This should solve your question.

Comment: Yes it absolutely did work! No I get it :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an issue with the file path.

The current directory on your code is the app root directory and `..` in the path represents its parent directory.

Consider your rails app resides under `parent_1/parent_2/parent_3/rails-mister-cocktail`, then the path you have used will search for the attachment under `parent_1/rails-mister-cocktail/app/assets/images/bar1.jpg`

Please find the below output from irb for better understanding:

```
2.6.3 :002 >  File.expand_path('../../app/assets/images/logo.png')
 => "/Users/mac1/Documents/RubyProjects/app/assets/images/logo.png" 
2.6.3 :003 > File.expand_path('app/assets/images/logo.png')
 => "/Users/mac1/Documents/RubyProjects/LiveProject/testapp/app/assets/images/logo.png"
```

Try the below:

```
bar1.photo.attach(io: File.open('app/assets/images/bar1.jpg'), filename: 'bar1')
```

You can also read the files relative to the root directory of your rails app.

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, %w(app assets images bar1.jpg)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to validate another answer but you helped a lot thanks!!!